# xcopy syntax? (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
xcopy /s/z/i Q:\U1210.exe C:\Users\jalozinski\Desktop\ 
START C:\Users\jalozinski\Desktop\U1210.exe
```

So this purpose of this code is to copy U1210.exe from the Q:\ drive to the desktop, then start the newly copied .exe. But for some reason it copies random folders and files from the Q:\ drive, and I don't know why. I have a feeling it has to do with the /s/z/i (i was trying these so it may be oen of them) or something to do with the filepath of the source. I feel like if I close the filepath it won't fix anything though.

This is batch, by the way. :I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at what you have for the XCOPY:
**/S** = Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
**/Z** = Copies networked files in restartable mode.
**/I** = If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.

First I would try w/o the **/S**, because you don't need directories.
I would include **/R** (Overwrites read-only files.)
I would also include **/Y** (Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.)

This is what I got working the way I think you want it:

```
@ECHO OFF
set source=Q:\U1210.exe
set dest=C:\Users\jalozinski\desktop\

xcopy %source% %dest% /Z /R /Y
start %dest%\U1210.exe
exit
```

Comment: Removing /S was enough, as it turns out. No wonder it was only pulling directories from the Q drive. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
xcopy Q:\U1210.exe C:\Users\jalozinski\Desktop\ 
START C:\Users\jalozinski\Desktop\U1210.exe
```

that should be all you need

/s is copying all the subfolders

/i is assuming it is a directory (when in doubt)

/z is a preventitive measure if you have a very slow computer

so you should not need any of those commands

Comment: /s was the reason it didn't work

and /i

also, we have pretty slow computers here. like 1gb of ram, Intel Core 2 Duo